# javascript, Highcharts, Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, highcharts, getelementbyid

I tried to use this code but it's not working :

```
var chart = $('#container-australien').highcharts();

var tempData = [document.getElementById('A58').value];
alert(tempData);

while(chart.series.length > 0)
chart.series[0].remove(true);

chart.addSeries({
    type: 'column',
    name: "R1", 
    data: tempData
});
```

I tried to replace `document.getElementById('A58').value` with 450 for example and it's working.
when I do an `alert(tempData)`, I have the correct result but it's not working with highcharts.

Do you know why I can't use `document.getElementById('A58').value` ?

Comment: This fiddle could help you ? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/ . Your `tempData` should be contains your json.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
the tempData must contain the Json dir or it can contain the Json content?

Comment: Do you have live example of your problem? It is possible that you are adding '450' string to your data instead of actual number. You may try using parseFloat() in this case: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz !
It's now working if document.getElementById('A58').value is a number but if for example document.getElementById('A58').value is a string like : {y : 750, date: '22/08/2010'}, it's not working anymore.

Comment: Right, and it won't because a string of `"{y : 750, date: '22/08/2010'}"` is not a valid set of values that the chart can interpret, it's a meaningless string. You need to parse the individual values out and pass them as valid arrays/objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found : 
On each input there is only one information.

```
var chart = $('#container-australien').highcharts();

var DateSeance = document.getElementById('A58').value;
var R1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A59').value);
var R2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A60').value);
var R3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A61').value);
var R4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A62').value);
var R5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A64').value);
var R6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A65').value);
var R7 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('A66').value);

while(chart.series.length > 0)
chart.series[0].remove(true);

chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R1",data: [{y: R1, date: DateSeance}]});
chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R2",data: [{y: R2, date: DateSeance}]});
chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R3",data: [{y: R3, date: DateSeance}]});
chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R4",data: [{y: R4, date: DateSeance}]});
chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R5",data: [{y: R5, date: DateSeance}]});
chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R6",data: [{y: R6, date: DateSeance}]});
chart.addSeries({type: 'column',name: "R7",data: [{y: R7, date: DateSeance}]});
```